# Difference via Python Dataframe Rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very big Series indexed by timestamp. I want to calculate (last_value - first_value) for a given time period.

For example:

```
timstamp              value
2016-11-08 00:00:00    1
2016-11-08 00:00:02    3
2016-11-08 00:00:03    -2
2016-11-08 00:00:07    6
```

On giving time window of 2 seconds, it should return:

```
2  [3 - 1]
-5 [-2 - 3]
0  [-2 - -2]
0  [6 - 6]
```

This is used to calculate profit series (forward return) for given time frame given prices at various points [Timestaps wont be continuous]. Also, since dataframe is very big, I want to be done in less time (Looping consumes a lot of time).

Edit: Profit series changed to look forward instead of backwards.

Additional test case (for 2 secs window):

```
time                      
2011-01-01 00:00:02.000  1
2011-01-01 00:00:04.000  2
2011-01-01 00:00:05.000  3
2011-01-01 00:00:05.500  4
2011-01-01 00:00:06.000  5
2011-01-01 00:00:06.500  6
2011-01-01 00:00:07.000  7
```

Profit series:

```
2011-01-01 00:00:02.000  1 [2-1]
2011-01-01 00:00:04.000  3 [5-2]  
2011-01-01 00:00:05.000  4 [7-3]
2011-01-01 00:00:05.500  3 [7-4]
2011-01-01 00:00:06.000  2 [7-5]
2011-01-01 00:00:06.500  1 [7-6]
2011-01-01 00:00:07.000  0 [7-7]
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
s.rolling('2001ms').apply(lambda x: x[-1] - x[0]).shift(-1).fillna(0)

timstamp
2016-11-08 00:00:00    2.0
2016-11-08 00:00:02   -5.0
2016-11-08 00:00:03    0.0
2016-11-08 00:00:07    0.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi! I actually required forward profits and have updated question accordingly.

Comment: @Rajs123 see updated post

Comment: But the last 2 seconds window wont necessarily be of one size.. It can be many rows

Comment: the `'2001ms'` specifies a 2.001 second window.  It accounts for that.  Why don't you provide data that spans the edge cases you're concerned with.  I can't help you any further than the effort you're willing to put into your question

Comment: Yes, I am just testing this out and creating edge cases.

Comment: Added test case